# Laravel-CORS: Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: javascript, laravel, rest, cors

Steps already taken:

- I have already used Fruitcake/laravel-cors, also did not work.
- Currently I tried making my own middleware

So I am running my front end on localhost Port 1220 while my Laravel endpoints are running on Port 1240. So my endpoints rest are on 1220 so I could simulate running my front end from a different host while my backend on another. They should not be within the same hosting.

On my current laravel setup I have created a middleware called Cors

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
      $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => '*'
      ];

      if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
      {
          return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
      }

      $response = $next($request);
      foreach($headers as $key => $value)
      {
          $response->header($key, $value);
      }

      return $response;
    }
}
```

And on my Kernel.php I included the Cors middleware on $middleware and on $middlewareGroups on web and api

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            EncryptCookies::class,
            AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            SubstituteBindings::class,
            // HandleCors::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            // 'throttle:api',
            // HandleCors::class,
            SubstituteBindings::class,
            AuthenticateSession::class,
            StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        ],

    ];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'sessions' => StartSession::class,
        'auth' => Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => Authorize::class,
        'guest' => RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

But after adding them I still get this error

***Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 1220***

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *You don't have permission to access this resource* doesn't sound like any CORS error I've ever seen in a browser, is that exactly what you see in a browser?

Comment: Yes. I have added a screenshot of what is returned on my network below

Comment: Yeah, that's not a CORS issue. What's the actual HTTP response error though, not the HTML that is sent as the response body for the error

Comment: I assumed it was a CORS issue because of the refer policy. But again I also edited my question and you should see the screenshot of the header and the HTTP code

Comment: can you add the content of `response` tab - i.e. the only truly useful information

Comment: just uploaded it

Comment: oops, sorry, that wasn't the useful bit. mea culpa. The useful bit was already there ... error 403 forbidden - that's the server saying you don't' have access to that resource - which isn't a CORS error - a CORS error would state that there's a CORS error

Comment: Seems you are calling a route (app/api/user/login). i'm wondering if you have a folder named app in your public folder? or is it part of your route? or did you renamed the public fodler?

Comment: no. "app" is the alias I used on my virtualhost. I upload the screenshot of my apache configuration

Comment: I've had weird issues happen with Laravel when two different domains duplicated laravel_session/XSRF-TOKEN in my cookies, so if you have changed any settings maybe check and clear those.

Comment: Don't implement your own middleware. Learn to properly configure an existing and proven one.

Comment: Your CORS middleware should occur much higher on the stack. It should be in front of any authentication middleware, since preflight requests are not authenticated.

Comment: Okay so we kind of figured it out. We couldn't host the front-end and the backend all in apache. so we served it using npm for the front end then pointed the urls to our apache server and it solved the issue. I'm going to close this question. Thank you for your help guys, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Serve using npm start (or serve using npm). The front-end and the back-end should be hosted separately. It cannot be all hosted in apache alone.